# Node.js do I have to define on "data" event for GET requests?

Tags: node.js

What if someone sends a GET request with a body, or a POST request but without a body. In both cases, do I have still have to define the on "data" event?

```js
request.on ("data", function (chunk) {

  // Might be a GET request or whatever.
  // Doesn't get fired when there is no body,
  // but must be present otherwise on "end" doesn't get fired

});

request.on ("end", function () {

  // Doesn't get fired unless on "data" is present
  // even if there is no body

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is this app?  Are you using express or some other framework, or purely node?

Comment: Just pure Node. I'm trying to understand how the flow really works and can't get nothing on this in the docs.

Comment: Node is pretty low level on it's own.  What express does in like 10 lines you'll have to write all kinds of stuff...

Comment: Yes I have noticed, but there is a crucial feature I have to do which AFAIK (I have done a lot of searches) is not implemented: multiple ranges + chunked + gzip and probably something else. I figure the only way to implement it is to build my own stream flow and for that I think I have to know exactly how it works.

Comment: POST emits evenets as has body, GET is just a query parsed from URL

Comment: Yes but anyone can send anything to the server. They don't need to conform to the RFC. A server must be able to handle anything thronw at it, including malformed requests.

Comment: @MarcK. So, it is time, when you are sharing code of your server that uses `net` class

Comment: I doubt you have to write the whole thing yourself. If you are wanting to create a custom stream you can chain pipes together to process the stream as needed. Check NPM for individual modules that do the different things you want, and chain them together.

Comment: Defining a `data` event handler is one way, calling `read()` on the stream until it has been consumed is another. See [the fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end).

Answer (score 0):

After a number of experiments, apparently defining **request.on ("data", callback)** doesn't hurt. I tried a number of malicious requests and Node.js appears to handle them fine.

However, if the request is GET and the client attempts to send a body, the underlying Node stream silently aborts the connection with *ECONNRESET*. The events **request "error"** and **response "finish"** don't get fired. This, in my opinion, is incorrect. I would expect to be able to do something such as log the request, *especially* if it's a malicious one.

If the request is POST but the client never send a body, then Node will eventually close the connection after the a timeout (default 2 minutes). This is the correct expected behavior.

**EDIT** I did some variations but this is essentially what I used.

```js
// The server
require ("http").createServer (function (request, response) {

 console.log ('server request headers', request.headers);

 response.on ("error", function (err) {
  console.log ('server response on error', err);
 });

 request.on ("error", function (err) {
  console.log ('server request on error ', err);
 });

 request.on ("data", function (chunk) {
  console.log ('server request on data:', chunk.toString ());
 });

 request.on ("end", function () {
  console.log ('server request on end');
  response.end ('Hello World');
 });

}).listen (12345);


// The client
var msg = 'Boo!';

var request = require ("http").request ({
 hostname: '127.0.0.1',
 port: 12345,
 method: "GET",
 path: '/test'
}, function (response) {

 console.log ('client response headers', response.headers);

 request.on ("error", function (err) {
  console.log ('client request on error', err);
 });

 request.on ("finish", function () {
  console.log ('client request on finish');
 });

 response.on ("error", function (err) {
  console.log ('client response on error', err);
 });

 response.on ("data", function (chunk) {
  console.log ('client response on data:', chunk.toString ());
 });

 response.on ("finish", function () {
  console.log ('client response on finish');
 });

});

request.on ("error", function (err) {
 console.log ('client request on error', err);
});

request.write ('Boo!');
request.end ();
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the code that's causing the `ECONNRESET`?

Comment: If you have your server instance (`.listen(12345).on(...)`) listen for [`clientError`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_clienterror) events you'll see why it closes the connection.

Comment: I tried by adding it to the code but nothing happened. **clientError** is not fired. I used **process.on ('uncaughtException',function (err) { console.log (err);});** and tried to remove the event callbacks one by one to see which actually get called. Result: none of them.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/83ef63f4d743199c31ca (this is the error I'm getting: `server clientError { [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 64, code: 'HPE_INVALID_METHOD' }`)

Comment: FWIW, the reason the HTTP parser throws an error is because it's not expecting a body. When your request sends a proper `Content-Length` header to the server it will work.

Comment: Ouch my bad! I didn't realize I had to bind it with server instead of the request/response. That is great. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, these types of errors happen before the request listener callback is even invoked (which is probably a good thing :-)